# Random allocation to groups

Tags: otree

I am coding a group treatment. I realised that there are several ways to randomly allocate players to groups. I am trying to understand which one is better suited for my experiment. For now, I am using subsession.group_randomly() and I am getting the desired result. Howerver, I also noticed that there is itertools which help in balanced allocation of players. I am not sure if groups.randomly() also helps to achieve that. Could you please advise me on the difference between these two codes and the pros and cons of them? I just need two players per group and I am also very new to coding.